# Minimal SRT Stream Example with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm having a hard finding a simple solution to showcase the `srt` streaming protocol with FFmpeg. The only [article](https://medium.com/@eyevinntechnology/using-ffmpeg-and-srt-to-transport-video-signal-to-the-cloud-7160960f846a) that I've found, is either going over multiple hoops to setup a stream. Is there no way to do a simple receiver/sender principle like in the old days with udp?

**Sender:**

```
ffmpeg  -i myfile.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 12 -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.5:1234
```

**Receiver:**

```
ffplay udp://192.168.1.5:1234
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `ffmpeg` needs to be compiled with `--enable-libsrt` to support the SRT protocol. See the output of `ffmpeg -protocols` to determine if it supports SRT.

Untested examples:

```
# stream copy
ffmpeg -re -i input.mp4 -c copy -f mpegts srt://192.168.1.5:1234

# re-encode
ffmpeg -re -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -b:v 4000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 8000k -g 50 -f mpegts srt://192.168.1.5:1234
```

See [FFmpeg Protocols Documentation: SRT](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#srt).

Comment: Problem is compiling ffmpeg is not trivial (I gave up after several hours) and I've not been able to find a recently compiled (Windows) version with srt enabled.

Comment: @MikeVersteeg [Zeranoe's ffmpeg builds](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) have SRT support.

Comment: Really? I checked two months ago and they didn't. Downloading..
Yep, it is now.. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I also miss comprehensive documentation and explanation on how to use SRT. However here is a minimum example I use:

**Sender** which acts as a listener and waits for connections:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c:v libx264 -f mpegts 'srt://:40052?mode=listener&latency=20000000'
```

**Receiver** which acts as a caller:

```
ffmpeg -i 'srt://192.168.1.345:40052?mode=caller' -c copy output.mkv
```